# NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/log4j/Logger.setLevel(Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;)

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using these log4j, slf4j and ch.qos.logback dependencies in my pom.xml of my java project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
```

I recently wanted to use an external servlet library and defined that dependency in pom. The init method of this servlet looks like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

....

public class HealthpageServlet extends HttpServlet{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HealthpageServlet.class.getName());

    protected HealthpageService service; 

    public static final String VERSION = "Healthpage-Version 0.0.4";

    public void init() throws ServletException {
        logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        .....
    }
```

My Weblogic Server shows me this exception from the init method, when i start the server:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org/apache/log4j/Logger.setLevel(Lorg/apache/log4j/Level;)V

When i in eclipse open that HealthpageServlet jar content, it has a log4j-1.2.15 jar inside the WEB-INF/lib folder. But even if i exclude that dependency from pom.xml, i see this exception and my server does not start. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the log4j Version (1.2.15) of my external jar was incompatible with the slf4j Version (1.6.4) of my parent project (where logger.setLevel() is not available), i had to update my slf4j to version 1.7.7.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer but adding this answer which might help others.
In my case, by trying different configuration I concluded that the log4j and slf4j to work successfully we need to find out the version match. The versions mismatch between spring-mvc and above two dependencies will result in the above error. So try to find out the **right version match between 3 dependencies**. I tried with below dependencies to get work done.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j13</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you go about finding the version of slf4j that is compatible with a version of log4j?